# How to find three vector on $xy$-plane such that in $\Bbb R^3$ be perpendicular?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, transformation

How to find three vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ on $xy$-plan of same length in $\Bbb R^3$ such that after the following transformation 
be mutually perpendicular?

$$\phi:\Bbb R^2\times \{0\}\to \Bbb R^3,$$
$$v\mapsto v+e_z$$
where $e_z$ is $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: What is $(1,2) + (3,4,5)$?

Comment: I believe that OP means "on the xy-plane of 3-space", i.e., vectors of the form $(x, y, 0)$. The notation for $\phi$ suggests that things *are* a little confused, however.

Comment: It seems that what was meant is that is the three vectors on the plane resides in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but has $0$ distance in the $e_z$ direction. Having said that, the transformation should have been defined as $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $v\to v+ e_z$

Comment: In regards to the question, the transformation seems to be an isometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identify $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$
throught the map $\mathbb{R}^2 \ni (x,y) \mapsto (x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$.
Let $v_1, v_2, v_3$ be the 3 vectors we seek
and $\ell$ be their common length.

In order for $v_i + e_z$ to be orthogonal to $v_j + e_z$ for any distinct pair $\{ i, j \} \subset \{1,2,3\}$, we need

$$(v_i + e_z)\cdot(v_j + e_z) = 0 \iff v_i \cdot v_j = -1$$

This implies the angle between $v_i$ and $v_j$ equals to $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{v_i \cdot v_j}{\ell^2}\right)$. Since this is the same for all 3 possible choices of $\{ i,j \}$, the angles among any pair of the 3 vectors are $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.
This leads to

$$-1 = \ell^2 \cos\frac{2\pi}{3} = -\frac12\ell^2\quad\implies\quad \ell = \sqrt{2}$$

To construct an explicit solution, just pick any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of length $\sqrt{2}$, rotate it clockwise and anticlockwise for $120^\circ$ and you are  done. One obvious choice is pick $v_1$ to be one along $x$-axis and this leads to following solution:

$$v_1 = (\sqrt{2},0),\quad v_2 = \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\quad v_3 = \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

Comment: very nice. thank you. one can say anything for similar question on $\phi:\Bbb R^3\times \{0\}\to \Bbb R^4$?

Comment: @C.F.G for 4 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the angle between all the pairs also need to be same. You can take $v_i$ to be vectors pointing from the center to the vertices of a regular tetrahedron. Since the angle for such a set of 4 vectors are known to be $\cos^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)$, $\ell = \sqrt{3}$ for this case.

Comment: Is your solution an isometry?

Comment: @C.F.G What do you mean isometry? You cannot find 3 non-zeros vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ perpendicular to each other.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The three final vectors must be perpendicular:
$$
(v1+ez)\cdot(v2+ez)=0\\
(v2+ez)\cdot(v3+ez)=0\\
(v3+ez)\cdot(v1+ez)=0
$$
which is, noting that $v_i$ lie in the XY plane:
$$
v1\cdot v2+1=0\\
v2\cdot v3+1=0\\
v3\cdot v1+1=0
$$
thus:
$$
x1x2+y1y2+1=0\\
x2x3+y2y3+1=0\\
x3x1+y3y1+1=0
$$

Properly fixing 3 of the 6 coordinates, for example $v_1$ and $x_2$, makes the system with a unique solution.